# Trying to display a user with the specific role in cakephp 2x

Tags: php, cakephp-2.9

I am trying to display table Users, and I want it to display the user with the role "Moderator" only.

```
public function moderators() {

    $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
    $this->User->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('User.role' => 'moderator')
));
```

This is my controller, and it seems that it is still displaying all  data in my table.

Comment: may i see your table? also you are not returning anything

Comment: This is my table
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1EqF.png

Comment: I am trying to have a SQL query result like this 
    [ SELECT * FROM users WHERE role = 'moderator' ]

Comment: $this->User->query("select * from users where role = 'moderator';");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use custom query for that:

```
$this->User->query("select * from users where role = 'moderator';");
```

Comment: Thank you for response, anyways i got the answer

Comment: public function moderators() {
 
         $moderator = $this->User->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array('User.role' => 'moderator')
            ));

             $this->set('users', $moderator); 
    }

Comment: This code works, refference https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html